# Badge for reaching the cap for reputation earned from suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Around a month ago, I reached the reputation cap of 1000 for suggested edits on Science Fiction and Fantasy. It would be very nice to have a gold or silver badge to brag about this.

Answer (score 7):

A badge related to suggested edits would be much harder to obtain after a user reaches 2000 reputation, and impossible after 20k reputation. In every other case, unlocking new privileges offers *more* chances at earning badges, not less. For that reason, I would rather not see such a badge.